# Sabre static data

Tags: sabre, static-data

I'm working with hotel APIs and faced a problem that I don't know what data I should send. I mean i don't know hotel IDs, countries and cities supported by Sabre.

I found a Multi-Airport City Lookup and Countries Lookup APIs. But they return only specified data, not all countries and cities.

I expect there are some APIs or csv files I can use to get static data about hotels, countries and cities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sabre recently uploaded a CSV file with both Sabre and Global properties under Dev Studio. It's under "Content Services for Lodging: API Support".